# Comparing the output of 2 commands using test without temporary variables

Tags: command-line, bash

I am testing a few things out in bash, and I decided to compare the number of lines in the file with the number of unique lines. I do know that I can simply make 2 temporary variables that store the corresponding values and just compare them but I was wondering about the way of doing it in 1 line.

For example, I though it this approach would work: `` test `wc -l filename` -eq `uniq filename|wc -l` `` . I get the error `-bash: test: too many arguments`. Where is my mistake and how would you do it without using temporary variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a direct comparison because `wc -l file` outputs `[number] file` and `uniq file | wc -l` outputs only `[number]`. You can do as @stelldriver suggested, redirecting the file to `wc`'s standard input with `wc -l < file`, so that only `[number]` is outputed, or use awk to get only the first field (see below).

Also, backticks are bad for readability. Prefer the `$(command)` construct.

You get "too many arguments" because your expressions are not quoted, so the shell splits the `[number] file` output into two words instead of only one.

All in all, this is what you are after:

```
test "$(wc -l file|awk '{print $1}')" -eq "$(uniq file|wc -l)"
```

We pass `wc -l file` output to awk so as to get only the first field, the `[number]`.

---

Just for more clarity in the answer, see what happens with your original attempt by prepending an `echo` to the command:

```
$ echo test `wc -l file` -eq `uniq file|wc -l`
test 19 file -eq 17
```

As can be seen, there are 4 arguments for the `test` command: `19`, `file`, `-eq` and `17`.

If you try the one I propose, you get a proper comparison with 3 arguments for `test`:

```
$ echo test "$(wc -l file|awk '{print $1}')" -eq "$(uniq file|wc -l)"
test 19 -eq 17
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did miss the fact that `wc` is also going to return the filename. Just one more thing, I suppose bash automatically converts the strings into integers in this case? After all, `eq` is an integer comparison, but the result that we get is represented by a string(when you put the result into quotation marks)

Comment: Yes, I was right after all. If I simply use the `test` with results quoted I get `test: : integer expression expected`. If I unquote it I get `test: -eq: unary operator expected`. If you can fix your answer I will accept it

Comment: @Alex.Kh You are welcome! No, the quotes do not convert the result in a string, they prevent word splitting. You should always [quote your variable expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). Some tools, such as https://www.shellcheck.net, will always warn you if you don't. Can you please show the exact command that raises `test: : integer expression expected`?

Comment: You can avoid the filename by redirecting via stdin i.e. `wc -l <file` in place of `wc -l file`

Comment: @Quasímodo. For example, `test "$(wc -l numpy_array.csv|cut -f1 -d' ')" -eq "$(uniq numpy_array.csv|wc -l)"
-bash: test: : integer expression expected` and another one is `test $(wc -l numpy_array.csv|cut -f1 -d' ') -eq $(uniq numpy_array.csv|wc -l)
-bash: test: -eq: unary operator expected`. `numpy_array.csv` is a file I am working with

Comment: @Alex.Kh Can you please show the output of `wc -l numpy_array.csv` alone?

Comment: @Quasímodo. I get this `     933 numpy_array.csv`. Unfortunately, markdown trims the space before 933 but it is there and it looks like a tab to me

Comment: @Quasímodo corrected my previous answer. It is inside the backticks

Comment: @Alex.Kh The problem is the leading spaces, that confound cut. Awk should do it: It is the same idea. Or try steeldriver's suggestion.

Comment: @Quasímodo. Thanks again for the explanation. The `awk` option works fine.